# Проверка активных аккаунтов кроном

Tags: cron

В базе есть 12 тысяч юзеров.Надо каждый день проверять их статус платежа на Paypal.Не будет ли большая нагрузка при использовании крона? или есть варианты получше.

Comment: А причем тут крон. он сам систему никак не грузит. он может процесс запустить а тот уже проверит сразу всех. правда сам подход с ежедневной проверкой 12к аккаунтов выглядит странно. БД и систему надо проектировать так, что бы не приходилось проверять какие то статусы.

Comment: А каким образом тогда проверять активные аккаунты?

Comment: например при платеже сразу фиксировать в БД дату до которой аккаунт активен

Comment: Датуя и так храню в бд.Идея в том что я использую переодические платежи,и может быть момент когда у клиента нет денег на счету и Paypal отменяет платеж. Так вот если платеж отменем мы должны сменить статус юзера на "Обычного пользователя".Так вот получается что всеравно надо кроном посылать запрос к PAypal для каждого юзера.

Comment: А paypal не умеет что ли сам сообщать об отмене платежа. О платежах точно умеет, значит и о других операциях должен уметь. В любом случае у них есть API что бы посмотреть все операции за период. Вот считывать их и проводить изменения в БД

Comment: И зачем вы вообще пытаетесь отталкиваться от периодических платежей. Какая разница прошела оплата за счет периодического платежа или обычным разовым. В обоих случаях paypal даст вам информацию о конкретном поступлении средств. на него и ориентируйтесь

Comment: Поставлена такая задача,чтобы автоматом каждый месяц совершалась оплата пакета!

Comment: ну и что то поставлена. преиодический платеж сам по себе, информация о пришедших деньгах сама по себе. помните про свои пакеты но работаете по фактическим платежам

Comment: Не совсем вас понимаю, как какая разница? То есть пользователю каждый месяц надо будет самому кликать на покупку пакета? вместо того чтобы один раз оплатить и далее автоматом оплачивать?

Comment: Да нет, зачем же. У пользователя периодический платеж стоит. Но вы ориентируетесь при работе на информацию о реально пришедших деньгах. Неужели когда в paypal подходит время очередного периодического платежа к вам на шлюз paypal не присылает оповещение о реально пришедших деньгах. не верю. ни одна платежная система не заставляет получателя денег самого отслеживать периодический платеж или обычный. информация о реальном поступлении всегда есть

Comment: Я понял.Вы про IPN

Answer (score 1):

> Не будет ли большая нагрузка при использовании крона?

программа *crond* (по умолчанию) и так работает постоянно, в режиме «демона», не создавая ни «большой», ни «маленькой» *дополнительной* нагрузки.

нагрузку могут создать ваши вызываемые программы/скрипты.

сам же факт пребывания добавленных вами строчек в конфигурационных файлах программы *crond* вообще не создаёт никакой «нагрузки» ни на что.